# Beautifulsoup can not find table containing specific class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.calculator.net/currency-calculator.html"

# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text


# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,'html5lib')
print(soup.prettify()) # print the parsed data of html

    
conv_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"cinfoT  "})

conv_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("tr")
```

I have written the above script to get the table listed on this particular website.
when i run the same conv_table comes as None type object.

If you visit the website, basically i want to extract the 2nd table bigger table and its class name contains "cinfoT  ". Also i have checked that there are some blank spaces in the class name.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is because this data is loaded by javascript. Try selenium. requests will give you plain html file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
DRIVER_PATH="Your selenium chrome driver path"
url = 'https://www.calculator.net/currency-calculator.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = html_soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'cinfoT ')
driver.quit()
print(table[0].tbody)
```

Comment: The code is running without any error.
But table is being generated as Nonetype object only.

Comment: Judging by your original question, There is a possibility you added ```cinfoT``` with two whitespace. While the class exists with one whitespace only hence the nonetype object.  Run the code as it is and you'll get output.

Comment: Yeah, You are right as i have added 2 or three white spaces.
When i checked in the website it was same, even though Nonetype object came as result.
I have used this below line (Not sure what it does).


html=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")


after passing the executable path in selenium.

Then i am able to extract tables based on index position.

It would be great if i can get to know what this statement did.

Thanks for support.